# Remove null columns from Pivot tsql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

I developed a pivot in tsql which resembles below:

```
MaturityBand    AAA     AA+     AA      AA-     A+      A       A-      Grand_Total 
Less than 1 yr  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    7.92    7.92
1 to 5 yrs      NULL    NULL    0.44    NULL    NULL    1.95    8.96    11.35
5 to 10 yrs     NULL    NULL    1.33    NULL    NULL    4.11    4.04    9.98
10 to 20 yrs    NULL    NULL    1.14    NULL    NULL    0.74    1.07    2.95
>20 years       NULL    NULL    0.15    NULL    NULL    NULL    0.14    0.29
Total           NULL    NULL    3.06    NULL    NULL    6.8     22.13   31.99
```

What i would like to do is remove the null columns so that above becomes below:

```
MaturityBand    AA      A       A-      Grand_Total 
Less than 1 yr  NULL    NULL    7.92    7.92
1 to 5 yrs      0.44    1.95    8.96    11.35
5 to 10 yrs     1.33    4.11    4.04    9.98
10 to 20 yrs    1.14    0.74    1.07    2.95
>20 years       0.15    NULL    0.14    0.29
Total           3.06    6.8     22.13   31.99
```

Is this possible?

(I can post my code if necessary.)

Comment: Do you want to remove only those rows now or every time a column is allways `NULL` you don't want to display it?

Comment: everytime a column is completely null i don't wish it to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

No, filters in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause work on rows, not on columns. If you don't want a specific column you can only exclude it manually from the `SELECT` clause.

```
SELECT 
MaturityBand, AA, A, [A-], Grand_Total 
FROM
(
   /*put your pivot query here*/
)some_alias
```

Here's an answer I wrote today for dynamic pivot (like aF. suggested in the comments).

[Dynamic Pivot Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220196/dynamic-pivot-query/11224988#11224988)

Have a try with it and let me know the result, please. Actually I would be surprised if this works.

Comment: Just wanted to add that, it's possible, yes, but it would be kind of ridiculous

Comment: Using `dynamic sql` for instance. If the values of a column are only `NULL` then the query won't select it.

Comment: thats the thing, i don't know which columns are null until the procedure has finished.  I'm trying to automate this so having no manual intervention.  So are you saying that it is impossible without manually selecting the columns you know are not null?

Comment: so how can i add dynamic sql to the script i've already written? or is it a complete rewrite?

Comment: @chrissyp Have a look at my edited answer, please. Should be easy to adjust to your needs.

Comment: @chrissyp you'll have to update your script to check the values on it and only select the columns not null using Dynamic SQL.