# using PIVOT on a rolling number of days

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

```
;WITH myRubbish AS
    (
    SELECT user, [20121231], [20130101], [20130102]
    FROM 
        ( 
        SELECT
            DateKey,
            user,
            revenue
        FROM    xxx.dbo.yyy
        WHERE DateKey > CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-4,112)
        ) x
        PIVOT
        (
        SUM(revenue)
        FOR DateKey IN ([20121231], [20130101], [20130102]) 
        ) u
    )
SELECT * 
FROM myRubbish;
```

How would I adapt this so that it can run every day and the columns are automatically re-named to the past 3 days?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11224988/971839

Comment: @halit nice reference - thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to implement a dynamic SQL version of the query. Similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(8), DateKey, 112))
                    from xxx.dbo.yyy
                    WHERE DateKey > CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-4,112)
                      -- and Datekey <= CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) -- include this is you want to limit the records
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [user],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                SELECT DateKey, [user], revenue
                FROM    xxx.dbo.yyy
                WHERE DateKey > CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()-4,112)
                  -- and Datekey <= CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)  -- include this is you want to limit the records
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(revenue)
                for DateKey in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: had a feeling this might lead back to dynamic sql

Comment: @whytheq Unfortunately, if you don't know the values of the columns to pivot, then your only option is dynamic sql